# Why Mathematica does strange thing with complex numbers

Tags: plotting, complex

For example, compare the two commands below.

```
ContourPlot[
 Abs[(Exp[I p] - 1) (Exp[I q] - 1)] == 0, {p, 0, 2 Pi}, {q, 0, 2 Pi}]
ContourPlot[
 Abs[(Exp[I p] - 1) (Exp[I q] - 1)] == 10^-10, {p, 0, 2 Pi}, {q, 0, 
  2 Pi}]
```

Obvisouly, $|(e^{ip}-1)(e^{iq}-1)|=0$ is only possible on the square boundary $p,q=0,2\pi$, but on my computer, Mathematica produces two entirely different graphs below.

[image]

Mathematica cannot give the correct result for the first command, while it does if we change $0$ to $10^{-10}$. I think it has something to do with how Mathematica manages errors with complex numbers.

I need to work with something much more complicated than this complex function, but I really don't know how to proceed if I can't make Mathematica correctly do this basic one.

Comment: From help, under possible issues it says `Contours f(x,y)==0 for functions where f(x,y)>=0 are always poorly detected: ` may be this is why?  `ref/ContourPlot`

Comment: @yarchik Thank you! I think this is a similar topic.

Comment: @Nasser But it doesn't tell exactly why and how to solve. LOL.

Comment: well, it says right after that `Giving a value in between allows for easy contouring:` may be this is meant to to be how to solve it. This explains why giving some value above zero makes it show up? I guess the lesson for us today, is to avoid using `Contours f(x,y)==0 for functions where f(x,y)>=0`

Comment: @Nasser Yep, but that's not a panacea. Try this one `ContourPlot[
 Abs[(Exp[I p] - 1) (Exp[I q] - 1)] == 10^-6, {p, -1, 2 Pi}, {q, 0, 
  2 Pi}]`. We set a nonzero value $10^{-6}$ and extend the plotting range of $p$ to $[-1, 2\pi]$, but this time it doesn't even show the $p=0$ vertical line...

Comment: I don't know exactly what *Mathematica* does, but a common contour plotting method is to sample the function on a grid and draw contours between adjacent grid points whose values straddle the intended contour levels. If the region within the contour is so narrow that no grid point samples it, you get no contour.

Comment: I like the problem in this Q, but it seems it would take some algorithm development to solve. That is, I don’t think there’s a built-in way that is robust enough.

Answer (score 3):

For this critical case `f[x,y]>=0` use `RegionPlot` as simple workaround:

```
RegionPlot[Abs[(Exp[I p] - 1) (Exp[I q] - 1)] <= .00001, {p, 0,2Pi}, {q, 0,2 Pi}]
```

[image]

Comment: @MichaelE2 Sorry I meant `f[x,y]>=0`. Yes it's quite similar, but my experience shows that `RegionPlot` evaluates more reliable in this case.

Comment: I see what you mean: that `RegionPlot` seems more reliable than `ContourPlot` when comparing `f[x,y]` to a small number, not that it handles the case when comparing to exactly zero.

Comment: That’s a good method, thank you!